# Count and Grouping 2 column in a table

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

This is my table and data

```
id | owner | buyer
1    1       3
2    2       2
3    1       2
```

I want the result to be like this

```
user | totals
2      3
1      2
3      1
```

User field means owner and buyer.
Hope you all are understand.
Thanks ~

Comment: Do owner UNION ALL buyer, GROUP BY its result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user, count(*)
from ((select owner as user from t
      ) union all
      (select buyer from t
      )
     ) ob
group by user
order by user;
```